# Campo fecha en el template

Tags: django

Tengo el siguiente campo en el modelo.py

```
      fec = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

pero a la hora de ingresarlo en el template con un formulario, me manda un error, diciendo que ese campo, no es editable, pero yo solo quiero que muestre la fecha actual en el formulario, que el usuario va a llenar

```
    fields = [ 'fec' ]
```

Apropósito, la zona horaria para Panamá, como seria? Ya sé, que es en el settings.py, pero no encuentro esa documentación, ayuda por favor <3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si solo quieres mostrar la fecha actual pudes hacerlo en tu HTML:

```
 {% now "Y-m-d H:i:s" %}
```

La zona horaria seria en tu setting.py:

```
 TIME_ZONE = 'America/Panama'
```

Comment: pongo en settings.py TIME_ZONE = 'America/Panama', asi porque de esa forma, me sale la hora, pero me sale otra hora, me imagino, que por la zona horaria, gracias por tu comentario compa